# Expanding Real Taylor series to Complex domain

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

> Suppose the restriction of $f:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ to $\Bbb R$ is real valued, and has Taylor expansion around $x_0\in \Bbb R$ at some $x_1\in\Bbb R$. Let's call $R:=|x_1-x_0|$. Then that power series given by Taylor expansion at $x_1$ converges for all $z\in \Bbb C$ with $|z-x_0|<R$. I know that this function derived by power series is unique, from the theorem 'Let $f$ be analytic in a domain $D$. Then $f$ is uniquely determined by its values in a domain or a line segment contained in $D$.' (by domain, I mean a nonempty, open, connected subset of complex plane.) But, how can we conclude that the function given by power series is equal to $f(z)$ for $z\in \Bbb C$ in radius of convergence?

(Let me make my question clearer with the help of a concrete example: Let $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be defined as $f(x)=\frac1{1+x^2}$. Now, it has Taylor series expansion, say at $x_1=\frac12$ around $x_0=0$ given by $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-x_1^2)^n$. So, we can conclude from this that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-z^2)^n$ converges for all $z\in\Bbb C$ with $|z|<\frac12$. But, then can we conclude that the extension of $f$ to complex plane, by just plugging $z$ in place of $x$, gives $f(z)=\frac1{1+z^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-z^2)^n$ for $|z|<\frac12$ without actually calculating power series again for calculating Taylor expansion again for $\frac1{1+z^2}$?)

Comment: Your function has domain $\mathbb R$. You cannot talk about $f(z)$ for non-real $z$. What is true is there exists an analytic function in $ \{z\in \mathbb C: |z-x_0| <R\}$ which coincides with $f$ on $(x_0-R,x_0+R)$.

Comment: @geetha290krm, sorry, editing to make it clearer

Comment: A function need not be given by  a simple expression like $\frac 1 {1+x^{2}}$. So simply replacing $x$ by $z$ and asking whether $f(z)$ is given by the power series does not make sense.

Comment: @geetha290krm, oh I see your point! thank you

Answer (score 1):

The answer is already hidden in your words. $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is analytic, and by definition, it is the extension of the function $f\vert_\mathbb{R}$. And the power series expansion you assumed was another extension of $f\vert_{\mathbb{R}}$ to the domain $\{z:|z-x_0|<R\}$. By identity theorem, both $f$ and the power series must coincide in the domain $\{z:|z-x_0|<R\}$.